# Re-align column in data frame into multiple columns

Tags: r

I'm trying to change a data frame column (`var3`, in the example below) that has multiple values for factor levels of another variable (`names`, in the example below). I'd like `var3` to be split into separate columns, one for each value, so that the factor levels in `names` do not repeat. My other variables (`var1`, `var2`) repeat where necessary to provide space for `var3`.

This is the kind of data I have:

```
df1 <- structure(list(name = structure(c(2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 
1L), .Label = c("fifth", "first", "fourth", "second", "third"
), class = "factor"), var1 = c(90L, 84L, 84L, 84L, 18L, 22L, 
22L, 36L), var2 = c(301L, 336L, 336L, 336L, 412L, 296L, 296L, 
357L), var3 = c(-0.582075925, -1.108889624, -1.014962009, -0.162309524, 
-0.282309524, 0.563055819, -0.232075925, -0.773353424)), .Names = c("name", 
"var1", "var2", "var3"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))
```

This is what i'd like:

```
df2 <- structure(list(name = structure(c(2L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 1L), .Label = c("fifth", 
"first", "fourth", "second", "third"), class = "factor"), var1 = c(90L, 
84L, 18L, 22L, 36L), var2 = c(301L, 336L, 412L, 296L, 357L), 
var3 = c(-0.582075925, -1.108889624, -0.282309524, 0.563055819, 
-0.773353424), var3.2 = c(NA, -1.014962009, NA, -0.232075925, 
NA), var3.3 = c(NA, -0.162309524, NA, NA, NA)), .Names = c("name", "var1", 
"var2", "var3", "var3.2", "var3.3"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

I've looked at `reshape` and `ddply`, but can't get them to give me this output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a base solution:

```
> df1$seqnam <- ave(as.character(df1$name), df1$name, FUN=seq)  # creates a "time" index 
> reshape(df1, direction="wide", timevar="seqnam",  idvar=c("name", "var1", "var2") )
    name var1 var2     var3.1     var3.2     var3.3
1  first   90  301 -0.5820759         NA         NA
2 second   84  336 -1.1088896 -1.0149620 -0.1623095
5 fourth   18  412 -0.2823095         NA         NA
6  third   22  296  0.5630558 -0.2320759         NA
8  fifth   36  357 -0.7733534         NA         NA
```

Comment: This works great on the example I gave, thanks. Unfortunately, in my real data, some of the values in `var1` and `var2` are not repeated where they should be and instead have `NA`s. This leads to the following error with `ave`: `Error in 1L:from : NA/NaN argument`. I'm trying to find a work around.

Comment: The reason I used `var1` as the first argument to `ave` what that it seemed that the fact 'name' was a factor was interfering with proper results. Try the new code using 'name'. (It's also better because it throws no warnings.)

Comment: Thanks a lot, that works great. I'll up-vote as soon as I have enough rep.

Answer (score 0):

```
ddply(df1, .(name), function(x) {
    var3 <- data.frame(rbind(unique(x$var3)))
    names(var3) <- paste0("var3.", 1:length(var3))
    return(data.frame(name = unique(x$name), var1 = unique(x$var1), 
    var2 = unique(x$var2), var3))
    })

 name var1 var2     var3.1     var3.2     var3.3
1  fifth   36  357 -0.7733534         NA         NA
2  first   90  301 -0.5820759         NA         NA
3 fourth   18  412 -0.2823095         NA         NA
4 second   84  336 -1.1088896 -1.0149620 -0.1623095
5  third   22  296  0.5630558 -0.2320759         NA
```

The function can be modified if you expect `var1` and `var2` to also contain multiple values.